# Saving result of function in session results in TypeError object not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, session

I have a function in a services.py file:

```
def someFunction():
 if choice == 'Choice1'
  result1 = Choice1.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
  result2 = Choice1.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
  result3 = Choice1.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
 elif choice == 'Choice2'
  result1 = Choice2.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
  result2 = Choice2.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
  result3 = Choice2.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]

  result = [result1, result2, result3]

 return result
```

I pass it to the view like so:

```
def template(request):
  request.session['result'] = someFunction() #save result to session


  result = request.session['result'] #retrieve saved result from session


  context = {
      'resulting': list(result)
  }
  return render(request, 'project/template.html', context)
```

And then passed to the template etc.

However this results in 'TypeError at /template object type of resulting is not JSON Serializable.'

If I don't try to save the function results to the session everything works fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way to achieve saving the result of a function to the session.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not "saving the results of a function", it's "saving a list of model instances". These are not directly serializable.

The best thing to do is to save only the IDs:

```
result = someFunction()
request.session['result'] = [item.id for item in result]
```

then when you need to get them back, fetch the items from the IDs, either individually to respect the ordering:

```
result = [Choice1.objects.get(id) for id in request.session.get('result', [])]
```

or get them in one go and sort by your list:

```
ids = request.session.get('result', [])
items = Choice1.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
result = sorted(items, key=lambda item: ids.index(item.id))
```

**Edit**

You need to check if the session already contains a result, if not get a new one.

```
result_ids = request.session.get('result')
if result_ids:
    # if we have IDs, get the matching items and use them
    items = Choice1.objects.filter(id__in=result_ids)
    result = sorted(items, key=lambda item: ids.index(item.id))
else:
    # otherwise, get new ones and store them
    result = someFunction()
    request.session['result'] = [item.id for item in result]

return render(request, 'project/template.html', {'resulting': result})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - request.session['result'] = [item.id for item in result] throws an error - 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: No it doesn't with the code you've shown above. And if your function returned IDs, then you wouldn't be getting the original TypeError in the first place.

Comment: Oh sorry i had an error in there! Thank you for your help, i'm no longer getting errors but the result of the function passed to the view is still refreshing on every page refresh :( I've marked you as correct as you did answer my question. Thank you again.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. If the code you've given above is what you're using, then of course it's changing on every request, because you always call `someFunction` and always store new values each time. Perhaps you mean to check if the session has a result already, if so use that rather than calling `someFunction`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes that's precisely what I wanted to do, could you advise?